# MySQL first_value on varchar column returns records in wrong format

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

first_value function in MySQL returns varchar column in unexpected format.

I got a table 'test' with two columns

```
create table test (col1 varchar(10), col2 integer);
```

and has records like this,

[image]

when I run first_value function I get records like this

```
select *, first_value(col1) over(partition by col1 order by col2 desc) as max_col1 
from test;
```

[image]

is this because first_value works only for numeric fields?

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-first_value-function/

Comment: Pls do not paste screen shots of code (or sample data) without providing the same as text. It makes it very difficult for people to recreate your environment. Please refer to the "complete" heading at  how to 
[create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this because first_value works only for numeric fields?

No, [`first_value()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value) works as well for the `varchar` data type.
The results you get are correct but in **hexadecimal** format!
`0x6B657931` is `key1`
`0x6B657932` is `key2`
`0x6B657933` is `key3`
So this could be a collation issue or a problem with the software you are using. 
If you are using a fiddle-like site, then it is not strange that the results come as they are. 
Anyway, you can find more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-syntax.html
If the problem persists, you can always use the [`unhex()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) function:

```
select unhex('6B657931')
```

will return:

```
key1
```

Or:

```
select CAST(0x6B657931 AS CHAR)
```

will also return:

```
key1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ce9c776fab3e037ca55ebd83fe9d9c2e).

Comment: I was using HeidiSQL, anyway your answer 'CAST(0x6B657931 AS CHAR)' worked for me! :)